# OpenGl with http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ tutorials

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, linker-errors

I have downloaded tutorial 0.3.8 from http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ then according to instruction I have build visual studio 2010 files by premake4.exe. But when I'm trying to debug project console shows for a second and in output shows:

```
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Bartek\Desktop\andagain\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\Tut 01 MainD.exe', Symbols loaded.  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file      
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file   
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ig4icd32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file  
'Tut 01 MainD.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'  
The program '[7932] Tut 01 MainD.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

@edit: I have windows 8 64-bit if it mean something to that.

Comment: Do you have installed the graphics drivers downloaded from the GPU vendor's website? Windows 8 doesn't ship with drivers supporting modern OpenGL. Those tutorials require modern OpenGL support and you get this only with drivers downloaded directly from NVidia, Intel or AMD:

Comment: The output you posted is not very useful, could you start `C:\Users\Bartek\Desktop\andagain\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\Tut 01 MainD.exe` from the command prompt and tell us if there's any output?

Comment: @PeterT: freeglut (Tut 01 mainD.exe): Unable to create OpenGL 3.3 context (flags 1, profile 1)

Comment: @datenwolf yes, I have NVIDIA driver (GeForce Gt 540M) 311.44.

Comment: This NVIDIA GeForce Gt 540M is a hybrid with intel graphic, if it change something @edit: so I run visual studio on GeForce not on Intel and project is building without any problem.. sorry tor taking time.

Comment: @Carlj28: Then this is probably [an Optimus problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071669/nvidia-optimus-card-not-switching-under-opengl/18071797#18071797).

Comment: @Carlj28 you should post this as your own answer and accept it, to get this question out of the "unanswered" pool

Comment: @PeterT ok sorry, I'n newbie :) done. edit: I can't accept my own answer.

Comment: @Carlj28 you can, you just have to wait 48 hours, which are up btw. so you can accept your own answer now. Also, consider adding your own answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521406/the-specified-file-is-an-unrecognized-or-unsupported-binary-format) as well, since it's also been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I run visual studio on GeForce not on Intel and project is building without any problem.. sorry tor taking time.

Comment: I have the same issue, can you explain what do you mean "run visual studio on GeForce" ? how you set VS to use the GeForce card?